# Rubygems installing an older version of gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, omniauth

I'm working in a simple sinatra app and I wanted to use the `omniauth-steam` gem.

I have in my Gemfile the following:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"
gem "tilt"
gem "shotgun"

gem "omniauth-steam"
```

when doing bundle it installs gems as expected. One of the dependencies of `omniauth-steam` is `omniauth-openid`.

The issue comes here, when `omniauth-steam` is installed, it grabs a wrong (I guess because it has an OLD version of that gem in their servers) version of `omniauth-openid`, because current branch of `omniauth-openid` in github (https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-openid) doesn't have the file `steam.rb` inside `lib/omniauth/strategies/` but the one that I got from rubygems does have it.

There's a closed issue in github that solves this (https://github.com/reu/omniauth-steam/pull/14). But I got the same `omniauth-openid` gem (with steam.rb) when doing bundle install

I tried to do the following:

```
gem "omniauth-openid", github: "intridea/omniauth-openid"
gem "omniauth-steam"
```

It does install the omniauth-openid without steam.rb, but when doing:

```
require "omniauth/strategies/steam"
```

it doesn't locate the gem that has been installed using github

How can I make `omniauth-openid` gem that I downloaded from github, visible for `omniauth-steam` so this gem can find that? or should I fix this issue by using another approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: look here http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html

Comment: @inye I really appreciate your link. It actually helped me to understand how to make github downloaded gems visible

Comment: great!! @JavierQQ23. mark your answer as the correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Gemfile`, you can specify the source of the gem like so:

```
gem 'omniauth-openid', :git => 'https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-openid.git'
```

Now when you run `bundle`, the omniauth-openid gem will be downloaded from the specified git repository.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did that and it downloaded the gem. My issue was that "omniauth-steam" didn't find this gem and used the one that is located in its own Gemspec.

Answer (score 0):

According to bundle docs (http://bundler.io/v1.9/bundler_setup.html)

```
Now that your code is available to Ruby, you can require the gems
that you need. For instance, you can require 'sinatra'. If you have a
lot of dependencies, you might want to say "require all of the gems in
my Gemfile". To do this, put the following code immediately following 
require 'bundler/setup':

    Bundler.require(:default)
```

So the beginning of my gemfile ended up like this

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"

Bundler.require
```

And now `omniauth-steam` finds `omniauth-openid` gem downloaded using github instead of the one that is specified in `omniauth-steam` gemspec